# How to make JDialog be the only accessible component?

Tags: java, windows, swing, desktop-application, jdialog

I'm trying to make a `JDialog` in java desktop application and I don't want the user to be able to click on any other frames until they closes the `JDialog`. It's more like a `JFileChooser`. When `JFileChooser` is called, user must select or cancel before they can have access on other frames. I have tried to use alwaysOnTop but user can still move to other frame. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your JDialog a [modal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModal%28boolean%29) dialog.

Better explained here: [How to Use Modality in Dialogs?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html)

Comment: ok.. it works for JDialog. How about a JFrame or JPanel, i don't see setModal in them..

Thanks anyway.. :D

Comment: Yes jpanel doesn't have setmodal but you can set this jpanel to a dialog with modality to make it modal. ;) And for jFrame you can not do it normal way, you have to make your hand dirty to do so, by overriding focus events of all the visible components. :x